# "Syntax error in SQL expression" SELECT query

Tags: sql, hsqldb, openoffice.org, openoffice-base

I have a MySQL DB connection using OOO Base and trying to create a SQL query

The error is as follows:

```
SQL Status: S1000
Error code: 1000

SQL syntax error
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT d.month, COUNT(e.key)
FROM event_table e, date_table d
WHERE d.key = e.key
AND d.year = '2013'
GROUP BY d.month;
```

Comment: Hi, it's a smallint in the MySQL DB

Comment: So consider to change `d.year = '2013'` by `d.year = 2013`

Comment: Thanks ok, I tried this and I'm getting the exact same three errors

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it, but the error you're getting *appears* to be related to `hashchk`. Though I don't know what that means, it can't be good. It *appears* to be directly related with the engine itself. It may also just mean the *service* isn't running.

Comment: Thanks, I have posted to the openoffice.org forum, perhaps some more info will come out from there :)